# Is there a implementation of retainAll() with custom Comparators?

Tags: java, collections, filter, comparator

I need to sift Collections according to contents of other Collections. Usually, I would have used the `Collection.retainAll()` method. 

Unfortunately, the equality of the domain objects I am handling is rather volatile, depending on the comparison context. Thus, I cannot rely on `equals/hashCode`. 
 My next reflex was to use a custom `Comparator`, but I was unable to find any methods supporting what I had in mind. Implementing the functionality is not a problem but I feel like reinventing the wheel here.
Have I missed something in the API? Other frameworks (not too esoteric) like commons are welcome too.
And if not, what optimizations would make my straightforward impl (creating a list of all Objects inside both Collections by going over all items of both Collections in n^2) a good one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest using [Guava's filter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html).  Alternative is to roll your own `retainAllBy(sourceCollection, Comparator)`.

Comment: could by done by wrapping a collection with a Predicate and then filtering. Sounds good. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Have I missed something in the API?

There is nothing in the Java Collection Framework that do a `retainAll` by anything else then the standard `equals` implementation.

---

Strongly depending on your usecase you can do it this way:

Create a Wrapper Object, that can be wrapped about your Objects, but with the `equals` method you need. And then use that wrappers to do the `retainAll` afterwards you need to unwrap the objects from the resulting collection.

But this way has two drawbacks:

- lots of objects will be created
- it does only work correct if the `equals` method of the wrapper is still a valid equals method in terms of the [java doc for equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) methods.

Comment: Thanks, I was almost sure about the Collection/s API itself, but just couldnt believe it :) Maybe there's another possibility (like commons or sth like that). I updated the question to extend to other libs

Answer (score 1):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) has a cumbersome solution to this problem, the [`Equivalence`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) concept. You wrap your objects in an equivalence using [`Equivalence.wrap()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html#wrap%28S%29), store the wrapped versions in collections and thereby make the collections use your custom equals / hashcode  logic.

I (and others) have requested [Equivalence-based sets and maps](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=576), but unfortunately the Guava team suggests that the above route should be taken instead.

Comment: +1: that was the API i was looking for while writing there is no support in core java

Comment: sounds rather complicated, makes me feel quite well off, using my rusty n^2 iteration method ;) Thank you. Guava seems really worth the effort though.