# Find the intersection between hashmaps using retainAll()

Tags: java, arrays

I need to find the intersection between 2 hash maps where the value is a String array, It seems that the retainAll() compares arrays by address, Is there any way to make  retainAll() works that way I expected?

```
String[] aa={"aa"};
String[] bb={"aa"};
Map<String, String[]> requestParameters=new HashMap<String, String[]>();
requestParameters.put("A",aa);
Map<String, String[]> redirectParameters=new HashMap<String, String[]>();
redirectParameters.put("A",bb);

Map<String, String[]> intersectionMap = new HashMap<>(requestParameters);
intersectionMap.entrySet().retainAll(redirectParameters.entrySet());
System.out.println(""+ intersectionMap.entrySet());
```

Comment: Please don't tag Java code as Javascript code snippets - they're not.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the background of the problem?  A map of arrays seems a bit unusual.  Are you restricted to solving your problem this way?

Comment: Sure, I am trying to find the intersection between the request.getParameterMap() and a list of possible redirect cases.  request.getParameterMap() --> Map<String, String[]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `retainAll()` method compares objects using their `equals()` method, which in the case of arrays compares their identities. The entry object just calls the key's and value's equal methods in [its equals method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and thus just calls the arrays equal method which doesn't work as one would expect. There are multiple ways to get around this problem:

One way would be to use [Guanva's filter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html) as described in andersoj answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7795872/5189673).

Another way would be to create a wrapper class for your string arrays that overwrites the equals method of this wrapper to compare the two arrays element by element. This was also described in the [answer by Ralph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7795669/5189673) to the same question as before.

If you want to get around the wrapper you can also use lists, as [their equals method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is implemented as you would expect. It will return true if both lists contain the same elements in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Could wrap the array:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {

  private static class StringArrayWrapper {

    private String[] data;

    public String[] getArray() {
      return data;
    }

    public StringArrayWrapper(String[] data) {
      this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
      return (other instanceof StringArrayWrapper) && Arrays.equals(data, ((StringArrayWrapper)other).data);
    }

    public String toString() {
      return Arrays.toString(data);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
      return Arrays.hashCode(data);
   }

  }

  private static StringArrayWrapper wrap(String[] a) {
    return new StringArrayWrapper(a);
  }


  public static void main(String[]args) {
    String[] aa={"aa"};
    String[] bb={"aa"};
    Map<String, StringArrayWrapper> requestParameters=new HashMap<String, StringArrayWrapper>();
    requestParameters.put("A", wrap(aa));
    Map<String, StringArrayWrapper> redirectParameters=new HashMap<String, StringArrayWrapper>();
    redirectParameters.put("A", wrap(bb));

    Map<String, StringArrayWrapper> intersectionMap = new HashMap<>(requestParameters);
    intersectionMap.entrySet().retainAll(redirectParameters.entrySet());
    System.out.println(""+ intersectionMap.entrySet());
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
[A=[aa]]
```

But normally, you'd want to intersect maps by key, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180488/intersection-of-java-util-map).

Comment: Why would you create a custom class to wrap the array instead of using `Arrays.asList` which already does what you need?

Answer (score 0):

try used this

```
static void intersection(String[]...inputArrays){
       HashSet<String> intersectionSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(inputArrays[0]));
       int a=0;
        for (int i = 1; i< inputArrays.length;i++){
            HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(inputArrays[i]));
            intersectionSet.retainAll(set);
        }
        System.out.println("======================");
        System.out.println("Interseksi nya");
        System.out.println("======================");
        System.out.println(intersectionSet);

    }
    public void test(){
        String[] inputArray1 = { "aku","kamu","dia","mereka"};
        String[] inputArray2 = {"dia","saya","mereka","aku"};
        String[] inputArray3 = {"aku","mereka","kita","dia"};        
        intersection(inputArray1,inputArray2,inputArray3);
    }
```

[image]